# Pulling out shapeless polymorphic functions that have dependencies

Tags: scala, shapeless

New to shapeless and I have a question on using polymorphic functions that need some dependencies. I basically have this code and want to pull somePoly object out of the run method:

```
import shapeless._
object SomeObject {
    type SomeType = Int :+: String :+: (String, Int) :+: CNil

    def run( someList: List[SomeType], someInt:Int, someWord:String ) = {

       object somePoly extends Poly1 {
           implicit def doIt = at[Int]( i => i + someInt + someWord.length)
           implicit def doIt2 = at[String]( i => i.length + someWord.length)
           implicit def doIt3 = at[(String, Int)]( i => i._1.length + someWord.length)
       }

       someList.map( _.map(somePoly) )
    }
}
```

One way I thought of doing it was like this, but it seems messy:

```
object TypeContainer {
  type SomeType = Int :+: String :+: (String, Int) :+: CNil
}
case class SomePolyWrapper( someList: List[TypeContainer.SomeType], someInt:Int, someWord:String ){
    object somePoly extends Poly1 {
       implicit def doIt = at[Int]( i => i + someInt + someWord.length)
       implicit def doIt2 = at[String]( i => i.length + someWord.length)
      implicit def doIt3 = at[(String, Int)]( i => i._1.length + someWord.length)
   }
}  
object SomeObject {

    def run( someList: List[TypeContainer.SomeType], someInt:Int, someWord:String ) = {

       val somePolyWrapper = SomePolyWrapper(someList, someInt, someWord)

       someList.map( _.map(somePolyWrapper.somePoly) )
    }
}
```

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Related gitter discussion https://gitter.im/milessabin/shapeless?at=56608190d2a5a7813cd41422

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limitations of Scala's implicit resolution system mean the `Poly` definition needs to be a stable identifier, which makes this kind of thing more painful than it should be. As I mentioned on Gitter, there are a couple of workarounds that I know of (there may be others).

One approach would be to make the `Poly1` a `PolyN`, where the extra arguments are for the `someInt` and `someWord` values. If you were mapping over an `HList`, you'd then use `mapConst` and `zip` to make the input `HList` have the right shape. I've never done this for a coproduct, but something similar is likely to work.

Another approach is to use a custom type class. In your case that might look something like this:

```
import shapeless._

trait IntFolder[C <: Coproduct] {
  def apply(i: Int, w: String)(c: C): Int
}

object IntFolder {
  implicit val cnilIntFolder: IntFolder[CNil] = new IntFolder[CNil] {
    def apply(i: Int, w: String)(c: CNil): Int = sys.error("Impossible")
  }

  def instance[H, T <: Coproduct](f: (H, Int, String) => Int)(implicit
    tif: IntFolder[T]
  ): IntFolder[H :+: T] = new IntFolder[H :+: T] {
    def apply(i: Int, w: String)(c: H :+: T): Int = c match {
      case Inl(h) => f(h, i, w)
      case Inr(t) => tif(i, w)(t)
    }
  }

  implicit def iif[T <: Coproduct: IntFolder]: IntFolder[Int :+: T] =
    instance((h, i, w) => h + i + w.length)

  implicit def sif[T <: Coproduct: IntFolder]: IntFolder[String :+: T] =
    instance((h, i, w) => h.length + i + w.length)

  implicit def pif[T <: Coproduct: IntFolder]: IntFolder[(String, Int) :+: T] =
    instance((h, i, w) => h._1.length + i + w.length)
}
```

And then you could write a more generic version of your `run`:

```
def run[C <: Coproduct](
  someList: List[C],
  someInt: Int,
  someWord: String
)(implicit cif: IntFolder[C]): List[Int] = someList.map(cif(someInt, someWord))
```

And use it like this:

```
scala> run(List(Coproduct[SomeType](1)), 10, "foo")
res0: List[Int] = List(14)

scala> run(List(Coproduct[SomeType](("bar", 1))), 10, "foo")
res1: List[Int] = List(16)
```

The specificity of the operation makes this approach look a little weird, but if I really needed to do something like this for different coproducts, this is probably the solution I'd choose.